# My two favorite scientists

Tags: visual, rebus, science

Who are my two favorite scientists ?

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find the chemical compound. Can you give us a text version?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What does that division signify?

Comment: @ev3commander - Glutamic acid is the chemical compound

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking if the glut**am**ic acid has to do with the AM on the right...

Comment: The atomic diagram is nitrogen, by electron (and proton) count, but of course might just be intended to convey a general atom.

Comment: Glutamic acid is also commonly abbreviated as 'glu', which could leave ten^5 under the fraction.

Comment: Frankenstein and Dr. Jekyll?

Comment: And 10^5 is One hundred thousand or Lakh(Indian naming).

Comment: Are they real scientists or as @JonMarkPerry is guessing, just fictional?

Comment: @ABcDexter; fictional, not real, bit like you!

Comment: Haha, no! i know these two, I'm just asking to OP :)

Comment: AM could refer to morning or Atomic Mass (more inclined towards Atomic Mass, since there is an atom)

Comment: Maybe the atom is "A to M"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first one must be

> Pascal

because

> one bar is 10^5 pascals (of pressure).
>
>  The actual cleverness here is in the 10^5 bit, which was solved by [Inazuma](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20499/inazuma) in the [comments section](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/34943/my-two-favorite-scientists#comment103292_34943) :
>  The chemical compound is Glutamic acid (GLU) and GLUTEN-GLU=TEN

The second must be

> Tesla

because

> The atomic diagram is nitrogen (N)
>  A Tesla equals one newton per ampere-metre (N/AM).

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: Great, you worked with simpler logic which worked efficiently :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to take an absolute swing at the second one:

> John Dalton

> Dividing the one nitrogen atom by its atomic mass of 14, we get 1u (1 dalton)

Comment: It's not John Dalton, sorry

Comment: How did you get 14 from AM?

Comment: @immibis I imagine by A = 1st letter of the alphabet, M = 13th letter of the alphabet A+M : 1+13 = 14

Answer (score 3):

Is the first one

> [Baron Kelvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Thomson,_1st_Baron_Kelvin)

as we have

> a "BAR" 'on'

and

> Gluten-Glutamic acid(also known as Glu)
>  Thus, Gluten-Glu=$10$
>  And, $10^5 = 100000$.
>  It is One hundred thousand, after half an hour of googling, I had to backtrack.
>  It's also [Lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)(as per Indian naming system). On wiki page its given:
>  "One lakh equals **100,000** troy ounces (3,100 kilograms) of a precious metal such as gold or silver".
>  Ok, so it has something to do with the units of measurement. And after some more search with scientist names, "**3100**" and "100000",  search results hit **Baron Kelvin**, where [Kelvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin) is the SI unit of temperature.
>  Also, I found [this page](http://www.westinghouselighting.com/color-temperature.aspx), in which
>  a line is given : "Color temperatures between **3100K** and 4500K are referred to as “cool white” or “bright white.”  As the background of [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AysZd.png) is *white*, so first one is most probably him.

Working on the right one:

> It's **N**itrogen atom in ground state on AM, no success(yet).

Comment: It is not Baron Kelvin, sorry.

Comment: Ok, but they do exist is this real world right? They are not fictional??